# Token doesnt show up when Deployed

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am completely new to coding. I really tried to get enough knowledge to copy my own Token together and get it to Work. My Problem is I use different open source codes but when I try to Deploy it via remix.eth.... the only contract that works to Deploy is "SafeMath". The Problem is whenever I deploy it via Safemath only the contract shows up, but no Token gets recognized. I even tried coppiying the Sourcecode of some similar Tokens...same Problem.
If I try to Deploy it with the "normal" contract of its Source code I get The following Error:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "gas required exceeds allowance (29882814) or always failing transaction" }
```

The source code is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.12;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed

interface IBEP20 {
  /**
   * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
   */
  function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

  /**
   * @dev Returns the token decimals.
   */
  function decimals() external view returns (uint8);

  /**
   * @dev Returns the token symbol.
   */
  function symbol() external view returns (string memory);

  /**
  * @dev Returns the token name.
  */
  function name() external view returns (string memory);


  /**
   * @dev Returns the amount of tokens owned by `account`.
   */
  function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

  /**
   * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from the caller's account to `recipient`.
   *
   * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
   *
   * Emits a {Transfer} event.
   */
  function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

 
  function allowance(address _owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

  
  function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

  
  function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

 
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);


  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}


contract Context {
  // Empty internal constructor, to prevent people from mistakenly deploying
  // an instance of this contract, which should be used via inheritance.
  constructor () internal { }

  function _msgSender() internal view returns (address payable) {
    return msg.sender;
  }

  function _msgData() internal view returns (bytes memory) {
    this; // silence state mutability warning without generating bytecode - see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691
    return msg.data;
  }
}


library SafeMath {
 
  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

    return c;
  }

 
  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
  }

 
  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    require(b <= a, errorMessage);
    uint256 c = a - b;

    return c;
  }

 
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
    // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
    // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/522
    if (a == 0) {
      return 0;
    }

    uint256 c = a * b;
    require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

    return c;
  }


  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
  }


  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    // Solidity only automatically asserts when dividing by 0
    require(b > 0, errorMessage);
    uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold

    return c;
  }

 
  function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    return mod(a, b, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");
  }

  
  function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    require(b != 0, errorMessage);
    return a % b;
  }
}


contract Ownable is Context {
  address private _owner;

  event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

  /**
   * @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
   */
  constructor () internal {
    address msgSender = _msgSender();
    _owner = msgSender;
    emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
   */
  function owner() public view returns (address) {
    return _owner;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
   */
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(_owner == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    _;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Leaves the contract without owner. It will not be possible to call
   * `onlyOwner` functions anymore. Can only be called by the current owner.
   *
   * NOTE: Renouncing ownership will leave the contract without an owner,
   * thereby removing any functionality that is only available to the owner.
   */
  function renounceOwnership() public onlyOwner {
    emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
    _owner = address(0);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
   * Can only be called by the current owner.
   */
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    _transferOwnership(newOwner);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
   */
  function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal {
    require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
    emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
    _owner = newOwner;
  }
}

pragma solidity >=0.6.2;

interface IPancakeRouter01 {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);

    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity);
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
    function removeLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function removeLiquidityWithPermit(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermit(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactTokens(
        uint amountOut,
        uint amountInMax,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactETH(uint amountOut, uint amountInMax, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) external pure returns (uint amountB);
    function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountOut);
    function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountIn);
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

// File: contracts\interfaces\IPancakeRouter02.sol

pragma solidity >=0.6.2;

interface IPancakeRouter02 is IPancakeRouter01 {
    function removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountETH);
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountETH);

    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
    function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable;
    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
}

pragma solidity >=0.5.0;

interface IPancakeFactory {
    event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint);

    function feeTo() external view returns (address);
    function feeToSetter() external view returns (address);

    function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair);
    function allPairs(uint) external view returns (address pair);
    function allPairsLength() external view returns (uint);

    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);

    function setFeeTo(address) external;
    function setFeeToSetter(address) external;

    function INIT_CODE_PAIR_HASH() external view returns (bytes32);
}


pragma solidity >=0.5.0;

interface IPancakePair {
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);

    function name() external pure returns (string memory);
    function symbol() external pure returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external pure returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);

    function DOMAIN_SEPARATOR() external view returns (bytes32);
    function PERMIT_TYPEHASH() external pure returns (bytes32);
    function nonces(address owner) external view returns (uint);

    function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external;

    event Mint(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1);
    event Burn(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, address indexed to);
    event Swap(
        address indexed sender,
        uint amount0In,
        uint amount1In,
        uint amount0Out,
        uint amount1Out,
        address indexed to
    );
    event Sync(uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1);

    function MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY() external pure returns (uint);
    function factory() external view returns (address);
    function token0() external view returns (address);
    function token1() external view returns (address);
    function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast);
    function price0CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
    function price1CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
    function kLast() external view returns (uint);

    function mint(address to) external returns (uint liquidity);
    function burn(address to) external returns (uint amount0, uint amount1);
    function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external;
    function skim(address to) external;
    function sync() external;

    function initialize(address, address) external;
}


contract ChumpChange is Context, IBEP20, Ownable {
    
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    mapping (address => uint256) private _rOwned;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _tOwned;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;

    address[] private _excluded;
   
    uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
    bool inSwapAndLiquify;
    uint256 private constant _tTotal = 20 * 10**9 * 10**9; // 20 Billion
    uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
    uint256 private _tFeeTotal;
    uint256 public _taxFee = 1;
    uint256 public _liquidityFee = 11;
    uint256 public _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
    uint256 public _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
    uint256 public _maxTxAmount = 100 * 10**6 * 10**9; // Max Transaction: 100 Million (0.5%)
    uint256 public _numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity = 50 * 10**6 * 10**9;
    uint256 public _maxWalletToken = 300 * 10**6 * 10**9; // Max Wallet: 300 Million (1.5%)
    
    IPancakeRouter02 public immutable pcsV2Router;
    address public immutable pcsV2Pair;

    string private _name = 'ChumpChange';
    string private _symbol = 'CCG';
    uint8 private _decimals = 9;
    

    event SwapAndLiquify(
        uint256 tokensSwapped,
        uint256 ethReceived,
        uint256 tokensIntoLiqudity,
        uint256 contractTokenBalance
    );

    constructor () public {
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
        
        IPancakeRouter02 _pancakeswapV2Router = IPancakeRouter02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
         // Create a uniswap pair for this new token
        pcsV2Pair = IPancakeFactory(_pancakeswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), _pancakeswapV2Router.WETH());
        pcsV2Router = _pancakeswapV2Router;
        
        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
    }
    
    modifier lockTheSwap {
        inSwapAndLiquify = true;
        _;
        inSwapAndLiquify = false;
    }
    


    function name() public override view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public override view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public override view returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _tTotal;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"));
        return true;
    }

    function totalFees() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tFeeTotal;
    }

    function reflect(uint256 tAmount) public {
        address sender = _msgSender();
        (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rAmount);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tAmount);
    }

    function reflectionFromToken(uint256 tAmount, bool deductTransferFee) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(tAmount <= _tTotal, "Amount must be less than supply");
        if (!deductTransferFee) {
            (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rAmount;
        } else {
            (,uint256 rTransferAmount,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rTransferAmount;
        }
    }

    function tokenFromReflection(uint256 rAmount) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(rAmount <= _rTotal, "Amount must be less than total reflections");
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        return rAmount.div(currentRate);
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }
    
    function removeAllFee() private {
        if(_taxFee == 0 && _liquidityFee == 0) return;
        
        _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
        _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
        
        _taxFee = 0;
        _liquidityFee = 0;
    }
    
    function restoreAllFee() private {
        _taxFee = _previousTaxFee;
        _liquidityFee = _previousLiquidityFee;
    }

    function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) private {
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        
        if (sender != owner() && recipient != owner() && recipient != address(1)) {
            require(amount <= _maxTxAmount, "Transfer amount exceeds the maxTxAmount.");
        }
        
        if(sender != owner() && recipient != owner() && recipient != address(1) && recipient != pcsV2Pair){
            uint256 contractBalanceRecepient = balanceOf(recipient);
            require(contractBalanceRecepient + amount <= _maxWalletToken, "Exceeds maximum wallet token amount (100,000,000)"); 
        }

        


        uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        
        if(contractTokenBalance >= _maxTxAmount)
        {
            contractTokenBalance = _maxTxAmount;
        }
        
        bool overMinTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance >= _numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
        if (
            overMinTokenBalance &&
            !inSwapAndLiquify &&
            sender != pcsV2Pair
        ) {
            contractTokenBalance = _numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
            swapAndLiquify(contractTokenBalance);
        }
        
        bool takeFee = true;
        
        //if any account belongs to _isExcludedFromFee account then remove the fee
        if(_isExcludedFromFee[sender] || _isExcludedFromFee[recipient]){
            takeFee = false;
        }
        
        if(!takeFee)
            removeAllFee();
        
        _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
        
        if(!takeFee)
            restoreAllFee();
    }

    function _transferStandard(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _reflectFee(uint256 rFee, uint256 tFee) private {
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rFee);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tFee);
    }

    function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getTValues(tAmount);
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, _getRate());
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
    }

    function _getTValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 tFee = tAmount.div(10 ** 2).mul(_taxFee);
        uint256 tLiquidity = tAmount.div(10 ** 2).mul(_liquidityFee);
        uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tLiquidity);
        return (tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
    }

    function _getRValues(uint256 tAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 currentRate) private pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rFee = tFee.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rTransferAmount = rAmount.sub(rFee).sub(rLiquidity);
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee);
    }

    function _getRate() private view returns(uint256) {
        (uint256 rSupply, uint256 tSupply) = _getCurrentSupply();
        return rSupply.div(tSupply);
    }

    function _getCurrentSupply() private view returns(uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rSupply = _rTotal;
        uint256 tSupply = _tTotal;      
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_rOwned[_excluded[i]] > rSupply || _tOwned[_excluded[i]] > tSupply) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
            rSupply = rSupply.sub(_rOwned[_excluded[i]]);
            tSupply = tSupply.sub(_tOwned[_excluded[i]]);
        }
        if (rSupply < _rTotal.div(_tTotal)) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
        return (rSupply, tSupply);
    }
    
    function _takeLiquidity(uint256 tLiquidity) private {
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        _rOwned[address(this)] = _rOwned[address(this)].add(rLiquidity);
    }
    
    function swapAndLiquify(uint256 contractTokenBalance) private lockTheSwap {
        // split the contract balance into halves
        uint256 half = contractTokenBalance.div(2);
        uint256 otherHalf = contractTokenBalance.sub(half);

        uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;

        // swap tokens for BNB
        swapTokensForBNB(half);

        // how much BNB did we just swap into?
        uint256 newBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);

        // add liquidity to uniswap
        addLiquidity(otherHalf, newBalance);
        
        emit SwapAndLiquify(half, newBalance, otherHalf, contractTokenBalance);
    }
    
    
    function swapTokensForBNB(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = pcsV2Router.WETH();

        _approve(address(this), address(pcsV2Router), tokenAmount);

        // make the swap
        pcsV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0, // accept any amount of ETH
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 ethAmount) private {
        // approve token transfer to cover all possible scenarios
        _approve(address(this), address(pcsV2Router), tokenAmount);

        // add the liquidity
        pcsV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
            address(this),
            tokenAmount,
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            owner(),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    receive() external payable {}
    
}
```